# What is `xargs -P 0` exactly doing, and is it a good idea to use it?

Tags: command-line

xargs provides a command `xargs -P 0`, the doc mentions that is spawns as many processes as possible to run the commands in parallel. But is it stopping, e.g., at the number of available CPU, or litterally several tens of thousands of threads? If it is the second option, isn't it less efficient than spawning around the number of CPU threads? I guess constantly changing between processes can take a non-negligeable time right?

Comment: What's `xparse` are you talking about? The only tool with this name I could find is related to parsing of [LaTeX3](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) documents, which doesn't sound like the tool you refer to. Could use provide a link?

Comment: Do you mean [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)?

Comment: Not all tasks are CPU bound.

Comment: @aviro Oooops sorry, yes, I meant `xargs`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas true, my use case is actually for tasks where the CPU is the bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, but `xargs` wasn't written for **your** use case, it's written for the general use case, and you shouldn't use `-P 0` when your processes are CPU bound; set your own limit instead.

Comment: @aviro sure, just wanted to get the confirmation. Meanwhile I did some benchmarks, and indeed `-P 0` is very bad, on cpu bound tasks, it makes the system really slow for around 200 processes, and is actually slower (2:05mn instead of 1:10mn) than with `-P 16` on my process when using 200 processes (I guess the time to switch between processes is the bottleneck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the test myself. So `-P 0` does try to run all processes at the same time (the limit being around the maximum number of allowed threads per the OS, which can be several thousands, I think), but it is a very bad idea to use it on CPU intensive tasks as this makes the system really slow.

I tested with around 200 `pdflatex` processes, and the overall running time is actually higher (2:05mn instead of 1:10mn) than with `-P 16` on my process when using 200 processes (I guess the additional time to switch between processes explains this). Moreover, with `-P 0` the whole OS is laggy and hard to use which is not the case with `-P 16`. (My cpu has 8 CPU threads.)